# Reviewing ANUDEM code for Topo to Raster in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, anudem

I wish to review the code for Topo to Raster (or Topo to Raster by File) to get a better understanding of its parameters and implementation in ArcGIS Pro.

I have located the `TopoInput.py` which contains the implementation of the TopoInput classes at ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\TopoInput.py

And a TopoToRaster wrapper in the `Functions.py` at ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py and then the trail runs cold.

Would anyone know where the code is located?

Comment: Well...that's the trouble with proprietary software - you do not get to see the algorithms behind the tools.  Still, this link provides some references to scholarly articles about Anudem. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/how-topo-to-raster-works.htm

Comment: Thanks @GBG.  I have also been through Hutchinson's papers, User Guides and basically any other material I can find which is helpful but does not describe specifically the ESRI implementation of the algorithm. ESRI's documentation is sparse and does not provide basic information like the valid range for each input parameter.  Eg. in the parameter description table [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/topo-to-raster.htm)  under "roughness_penalty" they say "if the primary data type is SPOT, the default is 0.5. Larger values are not normally recommended"